# Bibliography style similar to amsalpha but with no year

Tags: bibliographies

I have seen used a bibliography style similar to `\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}`, except the references look like e.g. "[Se], [Se 1]" for two different papers written by Serre rather than "[Se76]" and "[Se76a]" for two papers written by Serre in 1976. For some reason I like the first one better, even though it contains less information – maybe I just like that it takes up a little less space and looks simpler.

But what is the bibliography style? Can I get it using `\bibliographystyle{...}` with a built-in style, or is there something more complicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `amsalpha` already does pretty much everything you ask for, we 'only' need to find a way to drop the year from the label and turn the disambiguating letter into a number.

The required changes to the original `amsalpha.bst` are

```
--- amsalpha.bst    2020-06-01 17:00:10.000000000 +0200
+++ amsalpha-authoronly.bst 2020-06-25 08:46:04.906964900 +0200
@@ -1,3 +1,16 @@
+%%%% amsalpha-authoronly
+%%%% version of amsalpha without year in label
+%%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/551022/35864
+%%%% 2020-06-25 MW
+%%%%
+%%%% an unmodified amsalpha.bst can be obtained from
+%%%% https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amscls
+%%%%
+%%%% original (unchanged) copyright header follows
+%%%%
+%%%% (this does NOT imply any support or endorsement by any of the
+%%%%  organizations or people listed below)
+%%%%
 %% filename: amsalpha.bst
 %% version: 2.0
 %% date: 2000/03/27
@@ -1135,8 +1148,6 @@
     }
   if$
   duplicate$
-  year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #2 substring$
-  *
   'label :=
   year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #4 substring$
   *
@@ -1294,13 +1305,13 @@
 }
 
 FUNCTION {forward.pass}
-{ last.sort.label sort.label =
+{ last.sort.label label =
     { last.extra.num #1 + 'last.extra.num :=
-      last.extra.num int.to.chr$ 'extra.label :=
+      last.extra.num int.to.str$ "~" swap$ * 'extra.label :=
     }
-    { "a" chr.to.int$ 'last.extra.num :=
+    { #1 'last.extra.num :=
       "" 'extra.label :=
-      sort.label 'last.sort.label :=
+      label 'last.sort.label :=
     }
   if$
   author empty$ { editor empty$ { "" } 'editor if$ } 'author if$
@@ -1318,8 +1329,8 @@
 }
 
 FUNCTION {reverse.pass}
-{ next.extra "b" =
-    { "a" 'extra.label := }
+{ next.extra "~2" =
+    { "~1" 'extra.label := }
     'skip$
   if$
   label extra.label * 'label :=
```

- The first change (removing `year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #2 substring$`) drops the year from the label.
- Then we change `sort.label` to `label` on some occasions to ensure the extra.label information is calculated correctly.
- All other changes are concerned with switching from disambiguation letters to disambiguation numbers.

The file `amsalpha-authoronly.bst` which results from applying these changes can be downloaded from https://gist.github.com/moewew/91da90f4aa73084d5a365d0de7467c18.

With `\bibliographystyle{amsalpha-authoronly}` you then get

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby0,
  author    = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title     = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year      = {1980},
  publisher = {Pub \& Co.},
  address   = {London},
}
@book{appleby1,
  author    = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title     = {On the Ablative Case in {Greek}},
  year      = {1981},
  publisher = {Latin \& Co.},
  address   = {Oxford},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{appleby0,appleby1}
\bibliographystyle{amsalpha-authoronly}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: [App 1, App 2]]

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could do approximately this with Biblatex. (moewe's answer is the right one, but for reference I think this can be good to compare with, since Biblatex is generally easier to customize.)

Here I start with the standard style "alphabetic". I found the definition that creates the labels and removed the part about year from it. Then I would get labels like "Knua" and "Knub", so then I also changed the formatting of the "extra" field to add a space and the number as it is instead of converting it to alphabetics.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% Copied from biblatex.def but with three lines about year commented out
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
  }
  %\labelelement{
  %  \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
  %}
}

% In biblatex.def:
% \DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{\mknumalph{#1}}%
% Instead take the number as it is:
\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{~#1}

\begin{document}
\cite{kullback}
\cite{knuth:ct:c}
\cite{knuth:ct:b}
\cite{knuth:ct:a}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This gives the following:
[image]

I think you would have liked "Knu", "Knu 1" and "Knu 2" instead of "Knu 1", "Knu 2" and "Knu 3", but I haven't tried to do anything about that. (And frankly I prefer to have something explicit extra on all labels that need to be differentiated.)

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer! I can only accept one, but yours is definitely helpful.